# По клику на метку отображать поля из json

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api

По клику нужно отображать поля принадлежащие этой ссылке(метке на карте). Отображаю только Id метки, нужно вытащить остальные, `objectManager.objects.properties`; - не получается.

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
            if(document.querySelector('#div2').style.display == 'none'){document.querySelector('#div2').style.display = 'block';
              var objectId = e.get('objectId'),
        object = objectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = objectId + objectManager.objects.properties;
        } else
              var objectId = e.get('objectId'),
        object = objectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = objectId + objectManager.objects.properties;

});
```

1. Собственно у меня получается вытащить только Id метки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Сам Json file:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `e.get('objectId')` Ваш геттер на айди, я так понимаю. Что мешает глянуть что хранит в себе обьект `e` и достать нужное значение

Answer (score 1):

Каждую нужную строчку руками вытаскивать, это вот `objectManager.objects.properties` само все что нужно не выведет.

Должно быть что-то вроде такого для каждого текста: `objectManager.objects.getById(objectId).properties.balloonContent`

Ну и соответственно:

```
document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = objectId + objectManager.objects.getById(objectId).properties.balloonContent + ...
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое ! Я точно так же пробовал и многое другое, видимо из-за кэша не заметил результата. А подскажите в целом логика работы правильная ? То что я обращаюсь за параметрами в файл, и вывожу их через  innerHTML , или можно по другому, получше выводить?

Comment: заработало? это главное, насчет по-другому ничего не могу сказать,  не переписывать же с 0. В конец концов я лишь указала ошибку, а решение уже на ваше усмотрение.